# instaSharp oauthResponse Not work

Tags: c#, .net, instasharp

I want to use instaSharp to use instagram api , get followers anp posts and ... 
when I get code with callbackUrl I cant Send Requesttoken(code) 
and my oauthResponse is null ...
this is my code :

```
async Task getaouth()
    {
        var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_id"];
        var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_secret"];
        var redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirect_uri"];
        var realtimeUri = "";

        InstagramConfig config = new InstagramConfig(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri, realtimeUri);

        Session.Add("InstaSharp.config", config);


        // add this code to the auth object
        var auth = new InstaSharp.OAuth(config);

        // now we have to call back to instagram and include the code they gave us
        // along with our client secret
        var oauthResponse = await auth.RequestToken(code);

        // tell the session that we are authenticated
        //config.isAuthenticated = true;




        Response.Write(r.ToString());

        // both the client secret and the token are considered sensitive data, so we won't be
        // sending them back to the browser. we'll only store them temporarily.  If a user's session times
        // out, they will have to click on the authenticate button again - sorry bout yer luck.
        Session.Add("InstaSharp.AuthInfo", oauthResponse);

        // all done, lets redirect to the home controller which will send some intial data to the app
        //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        Response.Write("");
    }
```

after this my oauthResponse is null !
and after call this method 
_users.GetSelf()
i get it : 
**An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in        InstaSharp.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: You are not authenticated**

Answer (score 0):

Have you already registered your test client application on your account at Instagram developers?
If you haven't, sing in with your account [here](https://instagram.com/developer/), click on top-button "Manager clients" and add your test application to get the correct client ID and client secret informations.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way,

Install latest InstaSharp and just do this:

```
private InstagramConfig _config;
public async Task< ActionResult> somename(string code)
        {
            if (code != null)
            {
               _config = new InstagramConfig(["InstgramClientId"],
                                                 ["InstgramClientSecret"],
                                                ["InstgramRedirectUrl"]
                                                 );

                var instasharp = new InstaSharp.OAuth(_config);
                var authInfo = await instasharp.RequestToken(code);
                var user = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Users(_config, authInfo);

                ViewBag.Username = user.OAuthResponse.User.Username;
                ViewBag.Token = authInfo.AccessToken;


                return View();
            }

            return View("name"); 
        }
```

In your case, you have to make call to your method like:

```
var authresponse = await getaouth();
```

Make sure your calling function is async task.